# Sublime Text Editor

Tags: sublimetext

When I use the autocomplete for syntax; for example, the (anchor) Tags in Html
when i write

```
<a hr....
```

and let the editor complete it, The syntax format will normally show as below:

```
<a href="">
```

i want the editor to complete it but without write **">"** at the end, for ex, i want The syntax format to be like the syntax below:

```
<a href=""  (without ">")
```

how can i do that ?
But knowing that I can't edit it because I don't know which language the editor uses
I am a beginner

Comment: `<a href=""` this is not proper html systax, I think auto completion  is not customizable, at least not in free version.

Comment: This behaviour is only customizable by modifying the `html_completions.py` plugin that ships in the default `HTML` package to assume that it shouldn't close the tag by default. Note that this is always possible because there is no such thing as a "free version" of Sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short and better way to achieve what you want in SublimeText3 is by creating a Snippet:

*Tools > Developer > New Snippet*

paste the following code inside:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<a href="${1:link}"
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>a1</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html(.basic)</scope>
</snippet>
```

Now, in any HTML file, when you type `a1` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, it will auto-complete to `<a href="link"` with the word `link` selected. you can alter the snippet the way you find useful.

---

If you want to alter the default auto-completion for HTML in SublimeText3, you need to extract the HTML package from the program.

**I don't recommend this**, but if you are interested to know, you'll need to go through installing [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/) and then [Package​Resource​Viewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) then using it to extract the HTML package from the program then alter the files: `html_completions.py` and `HTML.sublime-syntax` which is a hard task to do, since removing the closing `>` tag will affect all syntax not just the `<a href="">` so you'll need to write a specific conditions to make it match only the part you want.